# How to display html formatted text in text area of java application?

Tags: java, swing, web-scraping

I am scraping data from web site using my java application and want to display the result after parsing code of html page in a Text Area made in Swing.

Text like: `hello <b>every</b>one` should be displayed as: 'hello **every**one' in text area.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a JEditorPane to display HTML or a JTextPane, which allows you to set attributes for specific characters. Read the API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial which provides examples.

Comment: Just a note: JEditorPane is good for relatively simple HTML and CSS but cannot display everything correctly like a decent modern browser can. Various versions of Java have slowly improved it but it is still not 100%. Sun announced a new component called JWebPane that is based on WebKit but so far it is vapourware.

Answer (score 7):

```java
JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
ep.setContentType("text/html");
ep.setText("html code");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see formated text inside of textarea( text in name of tag mean text not html). If you don't need to submit code inside area - you can use some style magic for div element. If you need to submit - use some WYSIWYG editor. There is [free one FCK](http://ckeditor.com/)